# Flags representing...?

Tags: knowledge, visual, flags

**What flag is missing? Explain why.**

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question mark should be replaced by the flag of...

> ...**NEPAL**.
>
>  [image: Flag of Nepal]

Because, noting that...

> ...there is **one flag/combination per continent** represented here:
>
>  Asia: [the unknown flag] & **Tibet**
>  South America: **Argentina**
>  North America: **USA**
>  Africa: **Tanzania**
>  Europe: **Russia**
>  Antarctica: *no flag* (because no countries)
>  Oceania: **Australia**

...we can note that these all represent the countries which...

> ...(using a specific definition of continental boundaries) are home to the **highest mountain on the continent**, also known as the **[Seven Summits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Summits)**:
>
>  Asia: **NEPAL** & **Tibet** = Everest (8,848m)
>  South America: **Argentina** = Aconcagua (6,961m)
>  North America: **USA** = Denali (6,194m)
>  Africa: **Tanzania** = Kilimanjaro (5,895m)
>  Europe: **Russia** = Elbrus (5,642m)
>  Antarctica: *no flag* = Vinson (4,892m)
>  Oceania: **Australia** = Kosciuszko (2,228m)
>
>  Note that for presentation purposes, the mountains have been ordered by decreasing height.

What was my 'in' for this puzzle?

> The first big pointer was the realisation that there was only one flag/combination per continent. This made me think we were looking for something that set that country apart from the others in its continent, something extreme...
>
>  The real 'kicker' was the flag of Tanzania. When casting about for what Tanzania might be renowned for, noting that it is home to Kilimanjaro - the highest mountain in Africa - blew everything wide open. The fact that Everest is on the border of two countries - one of which is the Tibet Autonomous Region - sealed the deal.